# twitter integration in phonegap ios

Tags: iphone, twitter, cordova, twitter-oauth, phonegap-plugins

i have developed a twitter integration page in xcode using phonegap.... i followed a instruction given in this site

http://oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms

and i set all the twitter plugin.js, plugin.m,plugin.h, and i build the twitterframe work a b i dint get any output.... kindly somebody help me to solve... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that article you reference was written in Oct of 2012 and uses v1 of the twitter API.  [Recently Twitter has retired v1 of their API](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired). So you would have to either find a different tutorial that uses the newest API or try and debug that old code to make it work with the new API.

Comment: OH..Thank you drew..  could yo please guide me to get through it.. actually i tried much... i think child browser may be the issue...

Comment: @Maniya I actually haven't worked with the new API so I'm not able to help sorry :(